# What is a max capacity of RAM Memory to motherboard Acer EA70_HB (U3E1)?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, motherboard

I have notebook Acer E5-771G-536Z. I have operating system Windows 10 Home Edit 64-bit but i have **4 GB DDR3L** of memory with speed 800Mhz. So it's going so slowly and I'd like to upgrade my memory Ram. I have motherboard **Acer EA70_HB (U3E1)**. I was trying to find information about max capacity of RAM Memory to motherboard Acer EA70_HB.

I have a question can someone please tell me what is max max capacity of RAM Memory to this motherboard (for example 16GB) and possibly max speed of 1 Memory Ram?

My notebook specs:

-OS: **Windows 10 Home 64-Bit**

-CPU: **Intel Core i5-4210U, speed: 1,7 Ghz (Turbo Boostup: 2,7 Ghz)**

-RAM Memory: **4 GB DDR3 L, 800 Mhz**

-Motherboard: **Acer EA70_HB (U3E1)**

-Graphic cards:

1. **Intel HD Graphics family**
2. **NVIDIA Geforce 840M (2 GB of Memory)**

Hard disk: **Western digital WDC WD5000LPVX-22V0TT0 - 500 GB**

P.S.: Maybe should I base on this below link of my current processor:

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/81016/intel-core-i5-4210u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-70-ghz.html

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: You have not properly identified your DDR3 module.  Please provide exact model number

Comment: I have identified by "Speccy" Software and I have DDR3 module of Memory RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDR3L 800 Mhz seems to be much too slow for your computer model.

The
[Crucial website](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/acer/aspire-e5-771g)
offers several DDR3L upgrades to the Aspire E5-771G, but also one DDR3 upgrade:
[Crucial 8GB Kit (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1866 SODIMM](https://www.crucial.com/memory/ddr3/ct2kit51264bf186dj/ct6086307)
($45.99).

Although Crucial is usually extremely accurate, I would still counsel to run the
Crucial
[Scan computer wizard](https://www.crucial.com/)
on the computer to verify that this upgrade is truly
applicable to your computer model. If it is so, then you could also search for
alternate RAM of exactly the same characteristics as the Crucial upgrade.
Crucial also offers a money-back option.

Comment: So as i go to the 2-nd link that Maximum memory is 16GB?

Comment: Seems like 8GB at 1866 Mhz, but better verify with the Scan computer wizard.

Comment: @Prochu1991 - Please edit your question you definitely do not have 800 MHz DDR3

Comment: Today I've just received 2 Memory RAM of 8 GB and the notebook works faster. Thank you for help!